# How to take a heap dump in windows with minimum downtime?

Tags: elasticsearch, jvm, heap-dump, jmap

I want to figure out why JVM heap usage on Elasticsearch node is staying consistently above 80%. In order to do this, I take a heap dump by running

```
jmap.exe -heap:format=b 5348
```

(5348 is the Process ID). Then I can analyze the dump with VisualVM.

The problem is that `jmap` pauses the JVM while taking the dump, so the node is basically offline for around 5 minutes.

[This article](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/03/so-you-want-your-jvms-heap/) suggests a faster approach that relies on taking coredump with `gdb` on Linux. I already tried WinDbg, which created a core dump, but I couldn't use it in VisualVM.

Is there a similar approach for Windows? How one can take heap dumps in seconds, not minutes?

Comment: I would make sure, a) you are using binary mode b) your heap is as small as possible to start with e.g. minimise heap size an trigger a full GC before taking the dump.

Comment: Hi Peter. I use binary mode, see my edited question and sorry for the confusion. I can not have smaller heap since this is production machine, running with lots of data.

Comment: Taking a heap dump isn't going to be cheap as it will have to stop the JVM to get all the data in a consistent snapshot.

Comment: @apangin - it may be clear *now*, but it wasn't when it was flagged as spam/offensive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After you've taken the coredump by `WinDbg`, you need to extract the heap dump from it by running

```
jmap -heap:format=b "C:\Program Files\Java\...\bin\java.exe" core.mdmp
```

This could be done offline; no interaction with running Java process needed. Then you will be able to open the generated `heap.bin` in VisualVM.

---

Alternatively you may take the class histogram. It is produced a way faster than full heap dump.

```
jmap -histo <PID>
```

It shows you the list of classes whose instances occupy the most space in the heap. This information is often enough to get the idea of where's the memory lost.