# Get error "windbg error:OpenDumpFile failed" when open the core dump with serviceability agent

Tags: java, debugging, jvm

I can successfully attach to Java live process by pid using serviceability agent ., however failed to open the core dump with it, and got error "windbg error:OpenDumpFile failed" when open the core dump with   serviceability agent .
[image]

BTW,I capture the dump with the following command , and it would hung if I omit the -F.

jmap.exe -F -dump:format=b,file=c:\temp\HeapDump.hprof pid

```
The environment:
win 7 64, JDK 7.0(hotspot)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A heap dump is not a core dump.

Heap dumps generated by `jmap` can be opened in the tools like VisualVM, Eclipse Memory Analyzer, YourKit Java Profiler etc.

Core dumps (or Minidumps in Windows terminology) are written by the OS or by the debuggers like `WinDbg`. `jmap` can also be used to [extract a heap dump from a minidump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35792936/how-to-take-a-heap-dump-in-windows-with-minimum-downtime/35822193#35822193).

Comment: It worked after I created the dump by Windows task manger. Under your guide for the SA recently days, I made a great progress on it, thank you for your kindly help:-) . 
BTW, it seems the core dump in Linux more like the full dump under Windows, as the mini dump just contains the threads related information ,
mini dump is more likely the thread dump for Java. http://download.microsoft.com/download/b/8/b/b8b36faf-00f1-460f-b32b-98a20102da4e/MemoryDumpFileConceptsandProcesses.doc

Comment: Just an additional note.  We were oddly getting a windbg error when the -F option was after the -dump option, but moving it to be the first option fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try to use jstack like this in the command line:

```
jstack 10776 e:\dump.txt
```

Replace the number `10776` with your own java process id.